# Increment product quantity in Order controller PHP Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

Can I, can we use increment on Laravel's project, I intended to use it in a store and update the controller?

I tried to make an update while storing data in the controller, working on product, order, and order detail models.

this is what I've got so far:

**App\OrderController**

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $order = Order::create($request->all());
        
        $products = $request->input('products', []);
        $quantities = $request->input('quantities', []);
        for ($product=0; $product < count($products); $product++) {
            if ($products[$product] != '') {
                $order->products()->attach($products[$product], ['quantity' => $quantities[$product]]);
            Product::where('id', $products[$products])->increment('qty',$quantities[$product]); 
            }
        }
    
        return redirect()->route('orders.index');
    }
```

so this line here is the question. can we do the increment like this on store function?

> Product::where('id',
> $products[$products])->increment('qty',$quantities[$product]);

I mean, I should have increased the quantity of the product after receiving the order right?

instead of succeeding, I got an error saying like:

> ErrorException (E_WARNING) Illegal offset type

I'm so stuck. please help.

Comment: nope, it still saying illegal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access an array using himself as the index. It should be `$products[$product]`, not `$products[$products]`

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $order = Order::create($request->all());
    
    $products = $request->input('products', []);
    $quantities = $request->input('quantities', []);

    for ($product = 0; $product < count($products); $product++)
    {
        if ($products[$product] != '')
        {
            $order->products()->attach($products[$product], ['quantity' => $quantities[$product]]);

            // $products[$product], without the 's'
            Product::where('id', $products[$product])->increment('qty',$quantities[$product]); 
        }
    }

    return redirect()->route('orders.index');
}
```

Comment: bloody, I was. it was.. typo killed me.

Comment: It happens with everyone! heheh. Sometimes it's better to use a different name for the index. ```$p``` or ```$productIndex```, in this case, would have prevented you from making this mistake.